# How to by pass _app.js in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

We recently updated Next.js and our login such as creating store in page level are started breaking. Next.js expect store should be passed through _app.js. My question is can we just bypass _app.js?

Comment: [from docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-app) Next.js uses the App component to initialize pages so I think it is impossible to bypass _app.js.